# Proof of $A \cup B = A \cup C \implies B = C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

How could I prove $A \cup B = A \cup C \implies B = C$?

Thank You!

Comment: That alone is false. Let $A = \Bbb{R}, B=[2,3], C = [1,2]$.

Comment: Its false take $A=B\cup C$.

Comment: You need to start the proof by assuming something false...

Comment: Either that or make an additional assumption which might be reasonable in some cases but isn't true in general - e.g. $A \cap B = A \cap C = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true, in general.

E.g., suppose $$B\subset A,\;C \subset A$$  Then $A\cup B = A\cup C =A$

As a concrete example, suppose $$A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\},\; B=\{1, 2\}, \;C=\{3, 4\}$$

Then $A = A\cup B = A \cup C$, but $B\neq C$.